# Same words in 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = []

for f in fruit:
    for ff in fruit1:
        if f == ff:
            same += f
print(same)
```

output is:

```
['p', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']
```

I am trying to see if the words are the same and add them in the 'same' list.
What is the right code for that?

Comment: Use `same.append(f)` instead of `+=`

Comment: The problem is not with your algorithm; the reason you get individual letters in the `same` list is because `+=` uses `.extend` for lists and not `.append`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple list comprehension like this,

```
same_fruits = [frt for frt in fruit if frt in fruit1]
```

You can as well use data structure in Python known as `set`, If you are aware of `set`, it allows you to get intersection.

```
fruit = set(['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange'])
fruit1 = set(['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes'])
same_fruits = fruit.intersection(fruit1)
```

**Update (Problem in your code)**

Your code does not work because, `str` type itself is a `iterable` in Python. So, when you use `+` operator with `list` and `apple` or `orange`, which is again a `utterable`, Python tries to `extend` instead of using `append` method. You could also make a small change in your code, to make sure that `str` is appended as a whole instead of treating it as individual components by exclusively using `append` method. Instead of `+` operator which in this case is extending `iterable` with another `iterable` , use `append` method.

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = []

for f in fruit:
    for ff in fruit1:
        if f == ff:
            same.append(f)
print(same)
```

Comment: Since you have more than 15 rep, I suggest you use the "flag" button to close duplicate questions.

Comment: _`str` type itself is a `list`_? both are iterables...

Answer (score 2):

try below one line code

```
same = list(set(fruit).intersection(set(fruit1)))
print(same)
```

['orange', 'pear']

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are the same lengths you can loop over just one list and compare the elements of each list and append them to the `same` list.

When adding to a list it is also important to use `.append()` as right now you're using `+=` which like mentioned in the comments uses `.extend`.

```py
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = []

for f in fruit:
    if f in fruit1:
        same.append(f)

print(same)
```

#### Output:

```
['pear', 'orange']
```

Comment: you do not have to check for f in fruit as it already iterates through that list

Comment: @Spounka Sorry didn't realize! Will update my solution thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = []

for f in fruit:
    for ff in fruit1:
        if f == ff:
            same.append(f)
print(same)
```

A better approach would be:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = []

for f in fruit:
    if f in fruit1:
        same.append(f)

print(same)
```

as this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with List comprehension :

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange']
fruit1 = ['pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes']
same = [f for f in fruit if f in fruit1]
```

you have logic errors in your code below:

```
for f in fruit:
    if f in fruit1 and f in fruit:
        same.append(f)
```

the question `and f in fruit` in the if statement is incorrect and redundant, because your for is runining on fruits items, so f is an item in fruit thats for sure. how you fix it? just omit this question.

```
for f in fruit:
    if f in fruit1:
        same.append(f)
```

Comment: That's literally the least efficient way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

For your general understanding. You have several list operations like append(), extend(), remove() etc

```
for f1 in fruit:
    for f2 in fruit1:
        if f1==f2:
            same.append(f1)
print(same)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in fruit
    if f in fruit1:
        same.append(f)
print(same)
```